# Swift hide just one button on tabbar

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, xcode6, uitabbaritem

I have seen lots of code to hide the whole tabbar. I am using tab bar controller in storyboard.
[image: Example of my tabbar]

If I had third and fourth buttons how could I hide just the second but still have 1, 3 and 4 buttons shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok to hide the button the following can be done. I used this code in a table view to add the editing function and change the title of the button based on the the click. But I modified it for this post just to show that when I clicked on the button again it would make it disappear.

```
var condition: Bool = true
@IBAction func buttonEdit(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if(condition == true) {
        tableView.editing = true
        sender.title = "Done"
        condition = false
    } else {
        tableView.editing = false
        sender.title = "" // This clears the title
        sender.enabled = false // This disables the button
        sender.image = UIImage() // This would clear the image
        condition = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well just hide the button itself.

```
button2.hidden = true
```

You will need to create an outlet.

```
@IBOutlet var button2 : UIButton!
```

And link it to the button in Interface Builder

Comment: Pretty sure thats not possible.

Comment: Ok I have tried the suggestion above but it dose not work. Let me rephrase the question as can I hide a relationship segue? And be selective on which ones to hide.

Comment: Also I do know that if I goto the view controller that I want to hide. And disable the bar item that it can not be selected. So can I add to that and hide it all together?